# php stdClass : assigning object value to variable

Tags: php, stdclass

Anyone know how to assign stdClass value to variable?

I have a stdClass object and when I print it using `var_dump($userdetails->emailaddress)`, it does print out the value as String(31)"asdas.@fsdf.com";

but when I try to assign the object value to variable, lets say:

```
$to = $userdetails->emailaddress;
```

the `$to` value become NULL ...

Anyone can help ?

Comment: That should work fine. For example, try: `php -r '$x = new stdClass; $x->foo = "bar"; $foo = $x->foo; var_dump($foo);'` It will print "bar". Paste your actual code, there's probably something else wrong with it.

Comment: This should work. Can you provide a complete example that displays the incorrect behavior? Have you checked that it's not an identifier case issue (such as $userDetails instead of $userdetails) ?

Answer (score 5):

That sounds like you are doing something wrong, because

```
$obj = new StdClass;
$obj->email = 'foo@example.com';
$to = $obj->email;
var_dump($to); // string(15) "foo@example.com"
```

Note that variables and object members in PHP are case sensitive (unlike functions and methods), so

```
$to = $obj->eMail;
var_dump($to); // NULL
```

However, in this case you also receive a PHP Notice

```
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$eMail
```

It is good practise to enable [`error_reporting(-1)`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) and the PHP.ini directives [`display_errors` and `display_startup_errors`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) on development machines.

---

*Since it's a CW. feel free to use this space for further debugging tips*

Answer (score 0):

I think there nothing wrong / prevent from assign value from stdClass to variable. Pls check the spelling of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Is the var public or not?

If the class is made like:

```
class Example
{
    public $emailaddress;

    public function example()
    {
        #do something
    }  

}
```

Then I can't see why there would be an issue.

Comment: It's a StdClass so any other visibility than public should not apply

Comment: Ah, I have never used a StdClass so I just assumed it was an example name.

My bad *blush*